# Iterating over an N-dimensional matrix with variable dimension sizes in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to iterate over an n-dimensional matrix where each dimension of the matrix also has a variable size.

I specifically want to have each elements multi-dimensional coordinate, like a `for loop` gives you `i` to access an element in an array.

I want to basically re-create a nested for loop like the following code with recursion where I could put any different kind of numbers into `dimensionSize`.

```cpp
std::vector<int> dimensionSize = {1, 4, 4};

for (int i = 0; i < dimensionSize [0]; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dimensionSize [1]; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < dimensionSize [2]; k++)
        {
            std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The results of this nested loop are...

```cpp
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 0 3
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
0 2 3
0 3 0
0 3 1
0 3 2
0 3 3
```

So far all of the examples/solutions I've found on traversing n-dimensional matrices in C++ have been really messy code and also for fixed dimension sizes e.g. 9x9x9 or 3x3x3.

However my matrix could be 1x256x513x3 or all kinds of sizes.

I currently have the following function which is close to getting what I want however it's got one problem.

```cpp
void iterate_over_n_dimensions (std::vector<int>& counters,
                                std::vector<int> dimensionSizes, 
                                int currentDimension)
{
    for (long i = 0; i < dimensionSizes [currentDimension]; i++)
    {
        print_counter (counters);

        if (currentDimension + 1 != dimensionSizes.size())
        {
            iterate_over_n_dimensions (counters, 
                                       dimensionSizes, 
                                       currentDimension + 1);
        }

        counters [currentDimension] ++;
        counters [currentDimension] %= dimensionSizes [currentDimension];
    }
}
```

Run with the following...

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> dimensionSizes = {1, 4, 4};
    std::vector<int> counters(dimensionSizes.size(), 0);

    iterate_over_n_dimensions (counters, dimensionSizes, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The results of this recursive function are...

```
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 2 
0 0 3 
0 1 0 
0 1 0 
0 1 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 3 
0 2 0 
0 2 0 
0 2 1 
0 2 2 
0 2 3 
0 3 0 
0 3 0 
0 3 1 
0 3 2 
0 3 3
```

You can see, the output repeats itself every time a nested for loop is completed! The repetitions at...

```
0 1 0 
0 2 0 
0 3 0
```

This problem gets worse the more dimensions I add. 
For examples a matrix of 1x4x4x2 repeats every time it completes it's 4th dimensional loop and more in other places.

If anyone could suggest a solution that is as cleanly written as my current function I would really appreciate it!

Right now I'm going to have to implement a massive switch statement with lots of for loops and capping the number of dimensions at 5 or so.

Comment: Note it's called _dimension_ not _dimention_.

Comment: does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Fixed the spelling! No it doesn't have to be recursive but I can't find a clean example of a non-recursive fix to this.

Comment: try flatten it to one dimension. makes most stuff easier.

Comment: @skeller the matrix is a very awkward byte array where each dimension has it's own bit-stride. I am trying to copy this to a Eigen matrix which you're right, can be flattened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to iterate all elements of the "n-dimensional matrix" (actually not called "matrix") and need a way to get all indices. I would start with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct multi_index {
    std::vector<size_t> dimensions;
    std::vector<size_t> current;
    multi_index(std::vector<size_t> dim) : dimensions(dim), current(dim.size()) {}
    void print() {
        for (const auto& e : current) std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    bool increment() {        
        for (size_t i=0;i<dimensions.size();++i) {
            current[i] += 1;
            if (current[i] >= dimensions[i]) {
                current[i] = 0;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};


int main() {
    multi_index x{{1,2,3}};
    do {
        x.print();
    } while (x.increment());    
}
```

And then adpapt it to the specific needs. Eg the vectors could probably be `std::array`s and depening on the actual container you probably want an easy way to access the element in the container without having to write `data[ x[0] ][ x[1] ][ x[2] ]`.

Note that often it is better to flatten the data into a one dimensional data structure and then just map the indices. Especially when the dimensions are fixed you can benefit from data locality. While the above lets you write a single loop to iterate through all dimensions you then need the reverse mapping, ie many indices to a flat index. The following is not thoroughly tested, but just to outline the idea:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
template <typename T>
struct multi_dim_array {
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::vector<size_t> dimensions;
    multi_dim_array(std::vector<size_t> dim) {
        size_t total = 1;
        for (const auto& d : dim) total *= d;
        data.resize(total);
    }
    T& get(std::initializer_list<int> index) {
        return data[flatten_index(index)];
    }
    size_t flatten_index(std::initializer_list<int> index) {
        size_t flat = 0;
        size_t sub_size = 1;
        for (auto x = std::make_pair(0u,index.begin());
             x.first < dimensions.size() && x.second != index.end();
             ++x.first, ++x.second) {
            flat += (*x.second) * sub_size;
            sub_size *= dimensions[x.first];
        }
        return flat;
    }
};
int main(){
    multi_dim_array<int> x{{2,2,3}};
    x.get({1,1,1}) = 5;
}
```

Once you store the multidimensional data in a flat array/vector writing a simple loop to iterate all elements should be straightforward.

PS: to be honest I didn't bother to find the problem in your code, recursion makes me dizzy :P

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! Recursion is horrible. I'm going to add your code to my post :)

Comment: @parkywolfy Don't add code that is already there on the page. Accepting the answer is the way that Stack Overflow works. When we see that green checkmark we know that it is you who accepted this answer.

Comment: @perkywolfy yes, "add your code to my post" if you mean your question, then please dont do it. Questions are for questions and asnwers are for answers. Your question is fine as is, if you add this code to your question it will be a bad question, and my answer will be superfluous

Comment: @user463035818 Alright then, I would like to reformat your code to be even more clear and attach it to this post for people to find. Would be best to do that in a comment? Or somewhere else? Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @parkywolfy imho the best would be to take the code and post a new answer (and dont forget to give credits ;), because this is my formatting style and, sorry, I dont think I would accept an edit that changes the style substantially (you could edit my answer, in case you dont know, or are you missing the privilege... dont remember...)

Comment: @parkywolfy you can answer your own question, and I'd be fine with you "stealing" my code, thats why I put it here, as long as you properly give credits

Comment: @user463035818 thanks for the info! I'll see what suits best. I wouldn't want to take any credit away from you.

Comment: @user463035818 also what did you mean by "actually not called "matrix"" in your answer?

Comment: @parkywolfy strictly speaking a matrix has two dimensions. A structure with more dimensions would rather be called tensor, which is a generalisation of the concept of  matrices to n dimensions

Comment: @user463035818 this could be why I couldn't find an answer before. thank you.

Comment: @parkywolfy I felt something was missing from the answer, I added something on how to flatten the multi dimensions. Btw I warned you ;) I feel pain seeing the `{` on the next line, so I really didnt feel like accepting your edit. I mean its a matter of taste, but it definitely isnt mine

Comment: @user463035818 awesome, I'll need to check that out sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question. If you want to visit each element of the multidimensional array once, the following code should do the job (counters in my case count the times each element has been visited so, at the end count, should be equal to dimensionSizes):

```cpp
void print_counter(std::vector<int>& counters)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < counters.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << counters[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void iterate_over_n_dimensions(std::vector<int>& counters,  std::vector<int> dimensionSizes,    int currentDimension)
{
    for (long i = 0; i < dimensionSizes[currentDimension]; i++)
    {
        counters[currentDimension] ++;
        print_counter(counters);
    }
    if (currentDimension + 1 != dimensionSizes.size())
    {
        iterate_over_n_dimensions(counters,
            dimensionSizes,
            currentDimension + 1);
    }
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> dimensionSizes = { 1, 4, 4 };
    std::vector<int> counters(dimensionSizes.size(), 0);

    iterate_over_n_dimensions(counters, dimensionSizes, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
1 3 0
1 4 0
1 4 1
1 4 2
1 4 3
1 4 4
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue because I want to visit each element once, not just "count the times each element has been visited". I also can not use the output of your algorithm since it goes out of the scope of the dimensions when I want to access each element using the counter as a coordinate.

Comment: it will visit each element only once, if not, counters art the end should have a different value

Comment: This answer does not even visit each element once, look at your output. The algorithm should generate every permutation of numbers starting with {0, 0, 0} and ending with {0, 3, 3}.

Comment: Ok I havne't fully understood your question